# Writing to Multiple Files in Python

Tags: python

I want to write "print 'hello'" to a bunch of *.py files in the same directory.  How do you do that?  I've searched all over the Web and SO, and I can't find out how.

Like in pseudo-code, "all files with *.py in a certain directory, open and write 'print 'hello'', close file".

I'm sorry, I'm a n00b, I just started learning Python.

Comment: Try writing out the actual pseudo-code. It will look remarkably similar to the real Python code.

Comment: Do you want to over-write the contents, or append to the file?

Comment: I want to append to the files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use glob:

```
import glob
for file in glob.glob("*.py"):
    with open(file, "a") as f:
        # f.write("print 'hello'")
        # etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `glob.glob` to select files by pattern.

```
from glob import glob
from os.path import join

for f in glob(join(DIRECTORY, '*.pyc')):
    # open f and write the desired string to it
```

Comment: using this, I made it:

from glob import glob
from os.path import join

for f in glob(join(DIRECTORY, '*.py')):
    # open f and write the desired string to it
    f = open("f", "wb")
    f.write( "Python is a great language.\nYeah its great!!\n");
f.close()

Comment: did I do that correctly?  I've got a feeling that I flubbed up really really badly

Comment: just tried it out, and it says that "DIRECTORY" isn't defined

Comment: it's a compiled python program, isn't it?

Comment: *.pyc are binary files containing the compiled Python bytecode. Trying to write to them might not be a great idea. (Of course, you can always just trash them and let the compiler re-compile them from the corresponding source.)